# system rescue cd failure reading sector from cd0

Tags: boot, rescue

Im trying to run system rescue cd on my HP4250 laptop and im getting a read error on the disk. Its saying the kernel needs to be loaded first, oddly enough, even though this is the place where i choose the kernel (before it loads).

The disk boots fine on another system, looks perfect condition, and is fairly new.

I saw another instance of a similar problem where a guy was running mint disk or somethign and this happened, and the one suggestion was to turn off secure boot.  What is that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for CD drives, especially in laptops, to age poorly and start to have read errors.

Secure boot is a technology that checks for cryptographic signatures in boot devices. Many users report being able to install mint on systems with Secure boot enabled. That said, mint says to disable it in the release notes:
http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_qiana_cinnamon.php

Look through the BIOS to disable secure boot as a troubleshooting technique.